# How to get current record ID in controller in Odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo

I want to update model from web controller , but I got this error when getting the current record id : 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

```
<form action="/update/teacher">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teacher_name" name="teacher_name"
               t-att-value="teacher_id.teacher_name"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>



@http.route('/update/teacher', type="http", website=True, auth="public")
    def update_teacher(self, **kw):
        http.request.env['academy.teacher'].browse(kw.get('id')).write(
            {
                'teacher_name': kw.get('teacher_name')
            }
            )
```

Any help please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure `id` is present in `kw`. For more details check [URLs and routing](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/website.html#urls-and-routing)

Answer (score 0):

```py
 http.request.env['academy.teacher'].sudo().browse(kw.get('id')).write(
```

Add sudo() before browse